# Change kendo ui Grid cell style

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have this column in kendo ui Grid

[image]

---

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Status).Width(60).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
```

---

this column takes only two values `Open,Closed`

I need to Add `class="label label-success"` When the `value = Closed`
And `class="label label-danger"` When the `value = Open`

thank you

Comment: This [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-conditional-set-the-visibility-of-the-command-edit-button-on-a-row-by-row-basis-#4u1jtFY7-k28ZWXjMOQYIA) could help

Answer (score 0):

```
columns.Bound(c =>c.Status).Title("Status").ClientTemplate("#if(Status=='Open') {#" +
                      "<label class='label label-success'>#=Status#</label>" +
                      "# } else {# " +
                        "<label class='label label-danger'>#=Status#</label>" +
                       "# } #").Width(60).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true));
```

Thanks Jayesh Goyani